# Deserialization fail due to new WCF DataMember

Tags: wcf, datamember

I have a WCF webservice that my C++ client talks to using a proxy generated by svcutil + wsutil.
I added a new DataMember, and now i get:

Serialization failure occurred when reading an element with WS_READ_OPTION '2', name 'GetMachineRequestDetailsResponse' and namespace 'M.NativeOM'.; Serialization failure occurred when reading a field with WS_TYPE '26 (0x1A)', WS_FIELD_MAPPING '2', name 'GetMachineRequestDetailsResult' and namespace 'M.NativeOM'.; An error occurred at row 1, column 796 (0x31C) when the XML reader is processing the input source.; An end element was expected.; A start element with the name **'UseForRun_SnapshotID**' and namespace 'M.NativeOM' was found, but not expected.;

My data members with in a datacontract is defined using Order attribute:

```
[DataMember(Order = 4)]
        public int MachineID { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Order = 5)]
        public string MachineName { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Order = 3)]
        public bool IsReserved { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Order = 13)]
        public string ReservedBy { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Order = 12)]
        public MdMachineRequestType RequestType { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Order = 0)]
        public bool CommandIsAdmin { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Order = 1)]
        public string CommandLine { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Order = 2)]
        public int CommandTimeout { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Order = 7)]
        public string MoveToDb_ServerName { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Order = 6)]
        public string MoveToDb_DatabaseName { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Order = 11)]
        public int Reimage_OsID { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Order = 8)]
        public int Reimage_ImageID { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Order = 9)]
        public int Reimage_OptionTimeout { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Order = 10)]
        public string Reimage_OptionUserName { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Order = 15)]
        public int UseForRun_RunID { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Order = 14)]
        public bool UseForRun_DoCleanInstall { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Order = 16)]
        public int UseForRun_SnapshotID { get; set; }
```

Also, the generated xsd file shows them in the right sequence

```
  <xs:complexType name="MdMachineRequest">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="CommandIsAdmin" type="xs:boolean" />
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="CommandLine" nillable="true" type="xs:string" />
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="CommandTimeout" type="xs:int" />
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="IsReserved" type="xs:boolean" />
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="MachineID" type="xs:int" />
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="MachineName" nillable="true" type="xs:string" />
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="MoveToDb_DatabaseName" nillable="true" type="xs:string" />
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="MoveToDb_ServerName" nillable="true" type="xs:string" />
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Reimage_ImageID" type="xs:int" />
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Reimage_OptionTimeout" type="xs:int" />
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Reimage_OptionUserName" nillable="true" type="xs:string" />
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Reimage_OsID" type="xs:int" />
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="RequestType" type="tns:MdMachineRequestType" />
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="ReservedBy" nillable="true" type="xs:string" />
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="UseForRun_DoCleanInstall" type="xs:boolean" />
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="UseForRun_RunID" type="xs:int" />
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="UseForRun_SnapshotID" type="xs:int" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
```

So using Order attribute did put DataMembers in the right sequence but my client doesn't just ignore new DataMember and instead give an error.

Answer (score 0):

the problem was that when i create proxy using wsutil, i was missing /ignoreTrailingContent option